# typescript Await is not working in callback

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

I have two functions and I am calling `cbf()` from `func()` through callback and I am using await but `after callback` comes first.

```
function cbf(name, callback: Function) {
    console.log(name)
    callback("123")
}

function async func() {
    await cbf("alice", function(aa) {
        console.log(aa)
    })
    console.log("after callback")  
}
```

Comment: `cbf()` needs to return a promise in order to `await` it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Promise

```js
function cbf(x) { 
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(x);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function f1() {
  var x = await cbf(10);
  console.log(x); // 10
}

f1();
```